How to write to last 4 bytes of disk via CLI? Like using dd, optional
Warning,
these commands (scripts) delete (change) data on your disk.
Be sure to back up any important data on disks/drives before proceeding.
You are responsible for lost data.
You can use
blkid
lsblk
to find out the correct device name.
Be sure to use the correct device name with dd.
Suggestion:
If you want to run these commands (scripts) below
then power-down and unplug Good disks and
then use a Spare disk with no data or
then use a Raw disk with no data, no partitions.
Remove all additional drives from the computer excluding
the drive you are booting from and
the drive you want to experiment on.
script1 works with bs=512.  last 512 bytes of disk = zero-fill
script2 works with bs=512.  last 512 bytes of disk = random-fill
script3 fails with bs=4.    last 4 bytes of disk does not zero-fill
6f4d 5db0 b676 ae28 35f7 2570 7e0e 4287  #result before script 3  bs=4  
6f4d 5db0 b676 ae28 35f7 2570 7e0e 4287  #result after  script 3  bs=4  
  "    "    "    "    "    "    "  0000  #desired last 4 bytes  

How to write last 4 bytes of disk via CLI?
Using dd is optional.
.
set variable, disk:
disk=sd_
#sd_=sda_or_sdb_or_sdc ...
.
script1 below, works on zero-fill last 512 bytes of disk:
clear
       disk_size_sectors=$(sudo blockdev --getsz /dev/$disk)      ; echo $disk_size_sectors   "disk_size_sectors  $disk  Get_size_in 512-byte_sectors."  
disk_size_sectors_minus1=$(echo $(($disk_size_sectors - 1 )))     ; echo $disk_size_sectors_minus1 "disk_size_sectors_minus1"  
sudo hdparm --read-sector $disk_size_sectors_minus1 /dev/$disk |tail -n1  
#  
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/$disk bs=512 \
seek=$(($(sudo blockdev --getsz /dev/"$disk") - 1)) count=1  
sudo hdparm --read-sector $disk_size_sectors_minus1 /dev/$disk |tail -n1  

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 # hdparm original end bytes  
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 # hdparm after script 1  

.
script2 below, works on random-fill last 512 bytes of disk:
clear       
       disk_size_sectors=$(sudo blockdev --getsz /dev/$disk)      ; echo $disk_size_sectors   "disk_size_sectors  $disk  Get_size_in 512-byte_sectors."  
disk_size_sectors_minus1=$(echo $(($disk_size_sectors - 1 )))     ; echo $disk_size_sectors_minus1 "disk_size_sectors_minus1"  
sudo hdparm --read-sector $disk_size_sectors_minus1 /dev/$disk |tail -n1  
#  
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/$disk bs=512 \
seek=$(($(sudo blockdev --getsz /dev/"$disk") - 1)) count=1  
sudo hdparm --read-sector $disk_size_sectors_minus1 /dev/$disk |tail -n1  

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 # hdparm before script 2  
6f4d 5db0 b676 ae28 35f7 2570 7e0e 4287 # hdparm after  script 2  

.
script3 below, does not zero-fill last 4 bytes of disk:
script3 bs=block size is less than 512 bytes, bs=4 :
clear  
       disk_size_sectors=$(sudo blockdev --getsz /dev/$disk)      ; echo $disk_size_sectors   "disk_size_sectors  $disk  Get_size_in 512-byte_sectors."  
disk_size_sectors_minus1=$(echo $(($disk_size_sectors - 1 )))     ; echo $disk_size_sectors_minus1 "disk_size_sectors_minus1"  
sudo hdparm --read-sector $disk_size_sectors_minus1 /dev/$disk |tail -n1  
#  
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/$disk bs=4 \
seek=$(($(sudo blockdev --getsz /dev/"$disk") - 1)) count=1  
sudo hdparm --read-sector $disk_size_sectors_minus1 /dev/$disk |tail -n1  

6f4d 5db0 b676 ae28 35f7 2570 7e0e 4287  #result before script 3  
6f4d 5db0 b676 ae28 35f7 2570 7e0e 4287  #result after  script 3  
  "    "    "    "    "    "    "  0000  #desired result after script 3  last 4 bytes = 0  

background:
command-line interface (CLI)
bs=block size
man dd
bs=BYTES
read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512);
overrides ibs and obs
What is the 'bs' option in dd?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021607/what-is-the-bs-option-in-dd#:~:text='bs%3DBYTES'%20Set%20both,smaller%20than%20the%20block%20size.
‘bs=BYTES’
Set both input and output block sizes to BYTES.
This makes ‘dd’ read and write BYTES per
block, overriding any ‘ibs’ and ‘obs’
settings.  In addition, if no data-transforming
‘conv’ option is specified, input is copied
to the output as soon as it’s read,
even if it is smaller than the block size.
using:
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'
hdparm v9.60
hdparm -V
dd (coreutils) 8.32
dd --version |head -n1
wxHexEditor version 0.24 Beta for Linux
use mouse to scroll to disk end after command:
sudo wxHexEditor sd_
How to write to last 4 bytes of disk via CLI?
Using dd, optional.
--

A "disk" (an HDD or SSD) is a block device, meaning that the data is stored in a fixed-sized sector. Any read or write operation must deal with a complete sector. To "write to last 4 bytes of disk" you would first have to read the last sector of that disk, modify the last 4 bytes of the sector in its memory buffer, and then write back that modified last sector. The dd utility is incapable of performing such operations in a single command.

@sawdust Doesn't Linux implement this mechanics transparently? E.g. the dd commands from this question just work. See this answer. What you wrote applies rather to "raw" devices mentioned there. What am I missing?

@KamilMaciorowski "Doesn't Linux take care of this mechanics transparently?" - Sure, when you use a filesystem. But not when you access a device node such as /dev/sdb

@sawdust Is Wikipedia wrong then? We are talking about block devices, not character devices.

@sawdust An example of what you were talking about is in this answer. But this is for pfSense, it is based on FreeBSD, the problematic device is a character (raw) device. In Linux we have block devices for disks; so there is no such problem, unless you use O_DIRECT (e.g. the direct flag in GNU dd). In Kubuntu I have just tried reading from my block devices with dd bs=1 count=1 skip=… and it works. It fails with iflag=direct.

@sawdust: Every Linux distribution I have used (there are many), macOS and dd fo Windows, do not require the bs operand for dd to be multiple of the sector size. I agree with what you wrote: "you would first have to read the last sector of that disk, modify the last 4 bytes of the sector in its memory buffer, and then write back that modified last sector." What fail to realize is dd does this when required transparently. In other words, dd does this for you. This is a simple example where you did not test before posting your comments.

Okay, I stand corrected. I played with the dd utility with a small bs value and a seek value, and got correct results which indicated a read-modify-write operation for the "output". Thanks guys for pointing out my ignorance. @KamilMaciorowski

@DavidAnderson "dd does this for you" – Strictly it's even better: the OS does this for dd in the first place, at least in Linux. When asked to read or write one byte, dd from GNU coreutils in Linux simply uses read(2) or write(2) with the count argument being 1. The magic is in the OS. One point of having block devices instead of (or along with) character devices associated with hardware is to not require each utility juggle block-aligned reads and writes on its own.


script3 fails with bs=4

It does not what you want because dd seek=, when given just a number, uses bs as the unit; but your calculation uses blockdev --getsz that counts 512-byte sectors, so it only works with bs=512, unless you recalculate.
To work with bytes, you don't need to recalculate. Get the size of the disk in bytes with blockdev --getsize64 in the first place. Decrement the value by 4, glue B to the end and use it with seek= of recent enough GNU dd. The B postfix informs GNU dd that the unit of this seek= is one byte (regardless of what bs is).
disk=sdX
disk_size=$(sudo blockdev --getsize64 "/dev/$disk") \
&& sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of="/dev/$disk" bs=4 count=1 iflag=fullblock \
           seek="$((disk_size-4))B"

I think your GNU dd is not recent enough for the above snippet to work. You need seek=… oflag=seek_bytes. In the recent GNU dd this flag is obsolescent. It should still work, but users should prefer the syntax used in the above snippet. You have no choice, use the below.
disk=sdX
disk_size=$(sudo blockdev --getsize64 "/dev/$disk") \
&& sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of="/dev/$disk" bs=4 count=1 iflag=fullblock \
           seek="$((disk_size-4))" oflag=seek_bytes

Notes:

iflag=fullblock because of the possibility of partial reads. In this particular case you want to write until the end of the disk, so you don't really need count=, dd will stop writing at no space left on device (but note it will report non-zero exit status); and if you drop count= then partial writes (if any) won't break anything, so you can as well drop iflag=fullblock. I did not drop them because in general (e.g. when writing to the middle of the disk) you will need them.

seek=…B and oflag=seek_bytes are GNU extensions. iflag=fullblock is a new addition to the POSIX standard (in 2024 when I'm writing this; for now with the wrong spelling though, bug report: here). When in doubt, you can always use bs=1 and recalculate count=. Then seek= without B will count bytes (even without oflag=seek_bytes) and there will be no need for iflag=fullblock. With bs=1 the tool will be slower than with bs=512, but this is negligible when writing just 4 bytes.

Do not embed $(sudo blockdev …) in the line with dd, do not run dd unconditionally. In the snippet I used &&, so if sudo blockdev … fails then dd will not run. In our particular case an empty value of $disk_size will result in seek=-4B and dd will complain, but in general you may want to do something like seek="$((var+4))B" and then empty $var may be disastrous.

The shell arithmetic in Bash does not work well with arbitrarily large integers (compare this question). Disk manufacturers introduce larger and larger disks, but Bash in your Kubuntu can handle integers of this magnitude. Still be aware that in general the shell arithmetic is limited and it does not catch overflows. Example:
a=111111111111111111111111111111  # stored as string
echo "$a"                         # retrieved as string
echo "$((a))"                     # trivially used in arithmetic expansion
echo "$?"




Kamil answers the question.
.
Remember above Warning about writing to disk.
.
calling Kamil's script -- script4
clear and echo and xxd and formatting added to script4
giving script5 urandom below:
disk=sdX  
clear  
disk_size=$(sudo blockdev --getsize64 "/dev/$disk") \
&& sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of="/dev/$disk" \
bs=4 count=1 iflag=fullblock \
seek="$((disk_size-4))" oflag=seek_bytes  
echo $disk_size " = disk_size in bytes "  
sudo xxd -d -s -0x100 /dev/$disk |tail -n1  

Confirm above script5 works.
There are at least 2 ways to confirm.
confirm1 of 2 with CLI, choose from 3 commands:
xxd -v
xxd 2021-10-22 by Juergen Weigert et al.
sudo xxd -d -s -0x100 /dev/$disk |tail -n1
echo
sudo xxd -d -s -0x100 /dev/$disk
echo
sudo xxd -d -s -0x100 /dev/$disk |grep -o -E '.{1,16}$' |tr -d '\n' 
confirm2 of 2 with GUI graphical user interface:
wxHexEditor version 0.24 Beta for Linux
use mouse to scroll to disk end after command:
sudo wxHexEditor /dev/sd_
.
script6, zero last 4 bytes
disk=sdX  
clear  
disk_size=$(sudo blockdev --getsize64 "/dev/$disk") \
&& sudo dd if=/dev/zero of="/dev/$disk" \
bs=4 count=1 iflag=fullblock \
seek="$((disk_size-4))" oflag=seek_bytes  
echo $disk_size " = disk_size in bytes "  
sudo xxd -d -s -0x100 /dev/$disk |tail -n1  

.
Expanding on above idea of writing to disk end = Last bytes of disk.
instead of last 4 bytes = 0000 add text of 4 bytes.
echo -n "end_" |xxd -p   #ASCII chars to ASCII hexadecimal  

656e645f
note 5f = _ = underscore
reverse above:
echo -n "656e645f" |xxd -r -p
end_
.
script7, last 4 bytes = end_
disk=sdX  
clear  
disk_size=$(sudo blockdev --getsize64 "/dev/$disk") \
&& echo -n "656e645f" |xxd -r -p |
sudo dd of="/dev/$disk" \
bs=4 count=1 iflag=fullblock \
seek="$((disk_size-4))" oflag=seek_bytes  
echo $disk_size " = disk_size in bytes "  
sudo xxd -d -s -0x100 /dev/$disk |tail -n1  

outputs:
1+0 records in  
1+0 records out  
4 bytes copied, 3.6066e-05 s, 111 kB/s  
120034123776  = disk_size in bytes  
120034123760: 6a56 fc72 880a 8270 1a79 7da2 656e 645f  jV.r...p.y}.end_  

note end_ at disk end
.
expanding more ...
write 100 bytes to disk end:
a 100 byte line is below, with spacing ...
_ _                                                 _  Disk record  _18-October-2024_     _Disk_End_
.
copy above 100 bytes into command below:
echo -n "_ _                                                 _  Disk record  _18-October-2024_     _Disk_End_" |xxd -p      #ASCII chars to ASCII hex
result of above 100 bytes of text for disk end
5f205f202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020  
202020202020202020202020202020202020202020205f20204469736b20  
7265636f726420205f31382d4f63746f6265722d323032345f2020202020  
5f4469736b5f456e645f  

.
for optics run script2 above,
random-fill last 512 bytes of disk:
.
script8, Customizing the last 100 bytes of disk
and use 3 confirming xxd commands ...
disk=sdX  
clear  
disk_size=$(sudo blockdev --getsize64 "/dev/$disk") \  
&& echo -n "5f205f202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020  
202020202020202020202020202020202020202020205f20204469736b20  
7265636f726420205f31382d4f63746f6265722d323032345f2020202020  
5f4469736b5f456e645f" |xxd -r -p |
sudo dd of="/dev/$disk" \
bs=100 count=1 iflag=fullblock \
seek="$((disk_size-100))" oflag=seek_bytes  
echo $disk_size " = disk_size in bytes "  
sudo xxd -d -s -0x100 /dev/$disk |tail -n1  
echo  
sudo xxd -d -s -0x100 /dev/$disk  
echo  
sudo xxd -d -s -0x100 /dev/$disk |grep -o -E '.{1,16}$' |tr -d '\n' ;  
echo  

1+0 records in  
1+0 records out  
100 bytes copied, 9.3131e-05 s, 1.1 MB/s  
120034123776  = disk_size in bytes  
120034123760: 5f20 2020 2020 5f44 6973 6b5f 456e 645f  _     _Disk_End_  

.
120034123520: 039b 528c e252 f7af f24a 17c7 f7a2 dc3a  ..R..R...J.....:  
120034123536: 1777 66ea 4c4c 63da 9548 f94a 8728 8475  .wf.LLc..H.J.(.u  
120034123552: 8b8d f45b 18f0 d8d7 0048 f009 aee1 4fe0  ...[.....H....O.  
120034123568: 0b9f d4d8 0027 351d e878 391b bf94 a71d  .....'5..x9.....  
120034123584: 4dfd d95d 3c7b 07ef 0055 6067 8ad5 57b9  M..]<{...U`g..W.  
120034123600: c7d2 1dee 86b6 3b75 4253 784c 1220 c75a  ......;uBSxL. .Z  
120034123616: ee58 cd99 026c f6fd 5d39 d016 137f 157d  .X...l..]9.....}  
120034123632: 3c02 dffc 5dd0 0c33 51c5 ddec 14e1 dca9  <...]..3Q.......  
120034123648: 3595 5ded aaf0 e00e b2fe c6b9 055e e065  5.]..........^.e  
120034123664: 23dd 1a5d 92ab 3509 0563 14d9 5f20 5f20  #..]..5..c.._ _  
120034123680: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  
120034123696: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  
120034123712: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  
120034123728: 5f20 2044 6973 6b20 7265 636f 7264 2020  _  Disk record  
120034123744: 5f31 382d 4f63 746f 6265 722d 3230 3234  _18-October-2024  
120034123760: 5f20 2020 2020 5f44 6973 6b5f 456e 645f  _     _Disk_End_  

.
..R..R...J.....:.wf.LLc..H.J.(.u...[.....H....O......'5..x9.....M..]<{...U`g..W.......;uBSxL. .Z.X...l..]9.....}<...]..3Q.......5.]..........^.e#..]..5..c.._ _                                                 _  Disk record  _18-October-2024_     _Disk_End_  

.
snapshot image of disk via wxHexEditor
note 100 byte message at disk end.

--
